# Funcion Asíncrona Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo una duda sobre una situación asíncrona, tengo la siguiente función:

```
    @override
      Future<Consulta> checkPayment() async {
        String url = 'http......'
    
        final response = await HttpClientAdapter.get(url: url);
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {

          final respuestaConsulta =
              Consulta.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
          
          // (1) PRIMERA LLAMADA EL RESULTADO ES PENDING
          // (2) SEGUNDA LLAMADA EL RESULTADO ES DECLINED
          print(respuestaConsulta.data.status); 


          if (respuestaConsulta.data.status == 'PENDING') {
            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), checkPayment);
          }
          // (3) SE EJECUTA AL FINALIZAR PERO EL RESULTADO SIEMPRE ES PENDING, 
          // DEBERIA RETORNAR EL RESULTADO DE LA TRANSACCION, EN ESTE CASO DECLINED
          return respuestaConsulta;
        } else {
          throw ArgumentError(response.body);
        }
      }
```

La idea general es que la función haga un long polling a la API hasta que el estado de la transacción sea diferente a "PENDING"; para ello, si el resultado no es el deseado,se ejecuta la función de nuevo con el Future para que se repita la llamada a la API.

Aparentemente todo funciona correctamente, pero tengo un solo inconveniente:

En el break (1) => El resultado es PENDING al tratarse de la primera llamada

En el break (2) => El resultado es DECLINED (Luego de volverse a ejecutar con el Future)

En el break (3) => El resultado aún es PENDING (aun después de volver a realizar las llamadas anteriores)

Por tanto, al realizar el llamado de la función, el resultado siempre será PENDING.

```
final check = await checkPayment(); // AQUI SIEMPRE RETORNA PENDING
```

El return no debería entregar el resultado de la última ejecución de este método?

```
final respuestaConsulta = Consulta.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estás retornando la segunda llamada.

```dart
 // (1) PRIMERA LLAMADA EL RESULTADO ES PENDING
          // (2) SEGUNDA LLAMADA EL RESULTADO ES DECLINED
          print(respuestaConsulta.data.status); 

          // Aquí solo la llamas, más no la retornas
          if (respuestaConsulta.data.status == 'PENDING') {
            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), checkPayment);
          }
          // (3) SE EJECUTA AL FINALIZAR PERO EL RESULTADO SIEMPRE ES PENDING, 
          // DEBERIA RETORNAR EL RESULTADO DE LA TRANSACCION, EN ESTE CASO DECLINED
          return respuestaConsulta;
```

Tendrías que hacer esto

```dart
 if (respuestaConsulta.data.status == 'PENDING') {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        return checkPayment();
   }
```

Comment: Ya decía yo que algo estaba haciendo mal, mil gracias como siempre Diego. Nos vemos en YT :)